# How do I easily append text to an existing file on my server?

Tags: http

I'd like to append some text from my iPhone app, to a file that already exists on my webserver.  What's the easiest way to do so?  I don't want you to write me code, just give me pointers on where to start and what I need running on my webserver (PHP?)

Initially, each app can post to a different file (i can figure out some unique identifier to help me with this).  Later I may wish to have all the data written to the same file, in which case I would need to be careful of concurrent access.

Also, I am not sure how authentication should work; should I require each user or app to have a different account and password, which would be hard to do since then I would need a way to create accounts from within the app.  Or I could embed a default username&password for all users, into the app - but that may open me up to some security issues.

What else am I missing?

EDIT:  I'm dropping the iOS tag as I think that this is more of a webserver question, and not an iOS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in order to append a string to a file on your server I'd have to say the easiest method is to send that string as a parameter of a HTTP request to your server. And then the server does the appending.

For authentication I think it would be best from a user experience point of view to use OpenID. That will provide you some kind of authentication and you would differentiate between your users but still , very important , will allow users to use their current accounts. I hate it when every service on the web requires me to make a new account just for that thing.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I'll look into using OpenID.  However, if I send a string to my web server, do I use POST or GET?  You imply GET.  And how do I specify that the string get appended and not to overwrite or create a new file?

Comment: Just make an NSURLRequest to a url like this www.your_adress blabla/service.php?action=append&string=myStringToAppend. I used JSPs only so far but I guess it's the same syntax. Then in your web service see if that action parameter is ""append" or "add" and perform the according action.